# How to create Processing challenges

Tags: security, encryption, authentication, client-server

I have an idea for my login and verification system but I'm wondering if its the correct idea or if its already been implemented somewhere else.

To try and mitigate some attacks, before login id like to propose a challenge to the client. So I'm thinking of proposing a computational challenge to the user. I need to somehow generate a problem or some kind of code that would take an average machine X seconds to process. With the answer being something that I could quickly calculate and check.

For instance, I know that hashing/encryption algorithms take time, perhaps I could use a simple encryption algorithm and generate some random short length password and a longer length key word. I then encrypt the keyword with the password, and send that to the client.

Then the client has to randomly guess/check the password and when it gets it, it sends me the key.

EXAMPLE:

```
Password:Foo
Length: 3
Answer: Bar
Keyword:123456
Output: encrypted(answer+keyword)->o3jubo3ibf32ib3o
```

SEND-> o3jubo3ibf32ib3o,Answer:Bar.

Then the client processes this and tries to come up with the password, guessing and checking if the first 3 letters = bar.

When it finds an answer, it sends me back a keyword and the password to check. I check if the keyword matches, if it does I continue, if it does not. I try to decrypt the challenge with the password they used to see if it does have the first 3 letters equal to the answer. If they ever give me a password that does not have the first 3 letters equal to the password- I blacklist the IP for 5 or so minutes and sever the connection.

Does this seem like it would work?

Has a library for this already been created?

Is there examples in c++ I can look at?

What would be the best encryption method for this approach?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What benefits do you gain from this versus traditional user authentication?

Comment: By introducing a cost to attempt login, I hope to try and mitigate proxy based login brute forces.